# Регулярное выражение, которое учитывает конкретное окончание

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст

```
 <td class="pageHeading" align="right" valign="top">891&nbsp;грн.    
     <span class="smallText">
```

Есть регулярное выражение:

```
var regExp=/<td class="pageHeading"\salign="right"\svalign="top">\S+/;
```

Как сделать, чтобы регулярное выражение учитывало, что поиск завершается на грн. ?

Пробовал такое регулярное выражение - не сработало:

```
var regExp=/<td class="pageHeading"\salign="right"\svalign="top">\S+(грн)/
```

Comment: Что означает "поиск завершается на грн."?

Comment: могут быть разные валюты, а мне нужно работать именно с грн.

Comment: Замените `\S+` на `\S+грн\.`. Ещё лучше на `[^<\s]+грн\.`

Comment: Есть еще какие-то варианты записи? Почему-то такое выражение находит значение в sublime, но в программке - нет.

/<td\sclass="pageHeading"\salign="right"\svalign="top">\S+грн/

Comment: Надо было указать, что должно остаться после поиска. Если надо до `грн`, в конце можно поставить `...\S+?(?=грн)`